# c# bool method, if boolean (argument) does not change, will method be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning c# and recently came across a sample exercise. I expect that this issue would be the same for any language with a boolean type. The exercise showed an example of code done wrong (intentionally). Here is the method in question: It is very short so I don't have a problem with posting it.

```
 public void CalculateCostOfDecorations(bool fancy)
  {
    if (fancy)
     {
         CostOfDecorations = (NumberOfPeople * 15.00M) + 50M;
     }
     else
     {
         CostOfDecorations = (NumberOfPeople * 7.50M) + 30M;
     }
    }
```

The point of this exercise seems to be (and correct me if I am wrong) that if the bool argument "fancy", is not changed from its initial state (by button push or other), then no matter how the variable "NumberOfPeople" changes, which is inside the method, the method itself is not called. Otherwise, if the bool argument "fancy" does change, then the method is called.

Is this correct? I have looked online but not found a suitable example.

Thank You

Perhaps I can clarify my question. I misspoke by asking if the "the method is called". I was referring to one of the statements in the method.

Lets say that initially the bool variable "fancy" is set to true. Then lets say that the method is called and "fancy" is not changed from true (which is was initially). The will the "if" statement testing the boolean (fancy) be entered if "fancy" is not changed?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: I'm not following the question.  What do you mean *the method itself is not called*.  The method is called if your code calls it.

Comment: Changing a variable changes a variable. Calling a method calls a method. The two are not linked.

Comment: "The exercise showed an example of code done wrong " what;s wrong with the code?  Looks fine to me...

Comment: This bothers me.. why is this method "incorrect" anyways

Comment: I have a feeling the *done wrong* part is something else from the sample exercise that was not posted here.

Comment: [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=UoRUBAAAQBAJ) to book if anyone "fancies" to read it. Page 204

Answer (score 3):

That assumption is close, but not quite correct.  I'm not sure how else to say this, but `CalculateCostOfDecorations` is called only when it is called.  A change in the value that feeds `fancy` will not trigger this method to be called; there needs to be an explicit call, binding, or other implicit action that causes `CalculateCostOfDecorations` to be called.

The reference `fancy` itself doesn't exist till this method is called and starts executing, and then only in the local scope of this method.

If you wanted CostOfDecorations to "always" be properly updated without having to call a method, and _fancy was also a member field (not shown in your example), you would do this by making it a read-only property:

```
private bool _fancy;
// ...
public Decimal CostOfDecorations { 
    get { return _fancy ? NumberOfPeople * 15.0 + 50.0 
                        : NumberOfPeople * 7.5 + 30.0; }  
}
```

Or, in C# 5:

```
public Decimal CostOfDecorations => _fancy ? NumberOfPeople * 15.0 + 50.0 : NumberOfPeople * 7.5 + 30.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding you if we invoke `CalculateCostOfDecorations` with first argument =`true`( ex. `CalculateCostOfDecorations(true)` the execution will continue with entering in the if statement, otherwise if the `fancy` argument is with value false it will enter into the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb and say without seeing how the exercise was worded that what they are asking you to think about is the variable `NumberOfPeople`. whose origins are not known based on your question.

I am going to guess that they want you to think about how that variable's scope is defined its scope and allocated (reference or otherwise). which would all influence the calculations outcome.

as others have said fancy can only be assigned a value when the method is envoked.